# Parse data from non structured file

Tags: java, parsing

Hi i would like to know how i can parse data from a non structured file. the data is like in a table but there is juste spaces. Here is an example :

```
DEST    ULD    ULD      XXX     NEXT    NEXT    XXX   XXX
        XXX/   XXX      TYPE/   XXX     XXX     PCS   WGT
        BULK   NBR      SUBTYPE NBR     DEST

XXX     BULK            BF                        0         
XXX     BULK            BB                       39         
XXX     BULK            BB                        1         
XXX     BULK            BF                        0         
XXX     BULK            BB                        0
```

I can't use delimiter as `useDelimiter("\\s{2,9");` because the spaces changes between column...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is called fixed-length format. In some ways it is easier. [What's the best way of parsing a fixed-width formatted file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609807/whats-the-best-way-of-parsing-a-fixed-width-formatted-file-in-java)

Comment: Great library `Flatworm` . Thanks for you're answer